# Cython : pure C loop optimization

Tags: python, loops, optimization, cython

Quoting the [Cython documentation](http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/language_basics.html#integer-for-loops):

```
Cython recognises the usual Python for-in-range integer loop pattern:
    for i in range(n):
        ...
If i is declared as a cdef integer type, it will optimise this into a pure C loop
```

I wrote two versions of a simple Cython function, one using the Python `range`, the other one using the `for-from` Pyrex notation (which is supposed to be deprecated):

```
 def loop1(int start, int stop, int step):
    cdef int x, t = 0
    for x in range(start, stop, step):
        t += x
    return t

def loop2(int start, int stop, int step):
    cdef int x, t = 0
    for x from start <= x < stop by step:
        t += x
    return t
```

By looking at `.c`file, I noticed that the two loops have been processed in a very different way:

The first one is actually creating a Python range, using Python objects. And it comes with 50 lines of unnecessary Python-to-C C-to-Python stuff.

The second one has been optimized into a nice pure C loop:

```
__pyx_t_1 = __pyx_v_stop;
__pyx_t_2 = __pyx_v_step;
for (__pyx_v_x = __pyx_v_start; __pyx_v_x < __pyx_t_1; __pyx_v_x+=__pyx_t_2) {
```

Am I missing something or is it a bug that I should report?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[The docs](http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/pyrex_differences.html#automatic-range-conversion) do mention this:

> ## Automatic range conversion
>
> This will convert statements of the form
> for i in range(...) to for i from ... when i is any cdef’d integer
> type, *and the direction (i.e. sign of step) can be determined*.

I suppose Cython wants to know the sign of step at compile time in order to generate `<` or `>` in the C loop's end condition.

See also [Ticket #546 on Cython Trac](http://trac.cython.org/cython_trac/ticket/546)

Comment: I also tried replacing `int` with `unsigned int` but the results remain the same. And I have no idea how to tell Cython the sign of the step.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is a very old question, but for people googling and ending up here I will post an answer.

https://github.com/cython/cython/issues/3310#issuecomment-707252866

```
for i in range(start, stop, step):
    ...
```

to this:

```
i = start - step
for _ in range(((stop - start) + (step - 1))//step):
    i += step
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, it is possible to convert *any* `for` loop over a range into a fully-optimized C loop, assuming the start, stop, and step are C variables.  You just have to write it a little cleverly.

Start with `loop1()`:

```
def loop1(int start, int stop, int step):
    cdef int x, t = 0
    for x in range(start, stop, step):
        t += x
    return t
```

Cython (currently) doesn't know how to optimize this because it doesn't know the sign of `step`.  As it turns out, the simplest solution to this problem is the solution to a slightly more general problem.  To wit:

```
def loop1(int start, int stop, int step):
    cdef:
        int x
        int count
        int t = 0
    for count, x in enumerate(range(start, stop, step)):
        t += x
    return t
```

The `count` variable looks useless, but a different version of the problem might use it in the loop body.

Now, calculate the index by hand:

```
def loop1(int start, int stop, int step):
    cdef:
        int x
        int count
        int length
        int t = 0
    length = len(range(start, stop, step))  # could optimize this further
    for count in range(length):
        x = start + count*step
        t += x
    return t
```

I have tried this, and I know it produces pure C code (except for the `length =` line).  In fact, I've successfully used it inside a `nogil` block.  `cython -a` shows all-white output for the loop itself.

This will create two extra variables, along with some dead stores etc., but I assume any halfway-decent compiler should be capable of eliminating those on `-O2`.  It is therefore suitable for high-performance loops.

Comment: It makes sense, but the Pyrex syntax `for x from start <= x < stop by step` is still more convenient if you know the sign of the step. It would be nice to have the `range(a,b,c)` syntax handled by Cython like discussed [here](http://trac.cython.org/ticket/546) though.

Comment: Last comment is 3 years ago, recommending a solution analogous to mine.  I've no idea what the Cython developers are doing right now, but that bug isn't it.